# Childs in div with class don't trigger the onmouseover without the same class

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, onmouseover

Question:
I want to have the to hide an div (`id="TestIdName"`) when another div (`class="IdName"` is onmouseover.
To detect the right id name, i'm using: ( `"TestBoxWindow" + event.target.classname` )
Because of that, when I don't add the class to the elements in the div (`class="IdName"`, it doesn't work because they don't have that class.

Is there a way to do it simpler or do I have to add `class="IdName"` to every element inside the `class="IdName"`?

The code:

HTML

```
<div class="SomethingElse">
    <div onmouseover="MyFunction(this)" class="IdName">
        <div class="IdName"></div>
        <p class="IdName">Search</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="TestIdName"
```

in Javascript

```
function MyFunction(x) 
    {
       document.getElementById("Test" + event.target.classname).style.display 
           = 'none';
    }
```

Comment: Try using `jQuery` and save yourself a lot of time and effort.

Comment: @Ankit Gautam - I removed that one to simplify the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="SomethingElse">
    <div onmouseover="MyFunction(this)" class="IdName">
        <div></div>
        <p>Search</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="TestIdName"
function MyFunction(x) 
    {
       document.getElementById("Test" + x.className).style.display 
           = 'none';
    }
```

Comment: i haven't used x.IdName in my program instead of it i have used x.className see carefully